# Do Hindus think two Sikh clans are descended from Lava and Kusha?

Tags: rama, other-religions, sikhism

It is said in Sri Dasam granth, authored by Guru Gobind Singh,  that the Bedi and Sodhi clan of Punjab are descendants of Kush and Lav respectively, the sons of SriRama.

It is said the Bedis got their name so because they studied the vedas for a long time , and hence came to know as 'Vedis' , or 'Bedis' (as 'B' = 'V' in many north indian accents)

I know hindus will not consider Sri Dasam as an authentic source, but i wanna know what they think of this subject as certain hindu authors have quoted Sri Dasam granth.

Comment: I edited the title to match the body of the question.

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in my question here, concerning a sect which seems to follow both Hinduism and Sikhism: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17757/36 I'm not sure if they consider themselves part of Sanatan Sikhs or if they consider themselves different.

Answer (score 2):

Title of your question is "How do Hindus view Sikhism and Sikh gurus ?"
but body of your question is about bedi and sodhi clan. Regarding body text of your question, i dont think there will be any text/view regarding bedi or sodhi being or not being vedi will be available. neither there will be any affirmation available, nor any objection available.

---

But regarding the title of your question "How do Hindus view Sikhism and Sikh gurus ?"

1) within hinduism, vedas, gita etc are common canonical text.
But there are many sects in hinduism, each sect has its additional canonical text.

Now, There are many sects in hinduism which consider sikh gurus as canonical . For example: Sanatani sikh , nanakpanthi , udasi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udasi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanakpanthi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanatan_Sikh

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sant_Mat

2) Among non-deminational hindus, there are many who rever sikh gurus as canonical as any other medeival age  great saints or bhakti saints (kabir,haridas,chaitanya..) . For example: myself. But there will not be any text mentioning this, because by definition they are non-denominational hindus.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Sanatan Sikh" . The entire article and content of it is invalid .

Comment: @Sikhandyeshallfind Are you saying that there is no one who calls themselves a Sanatan Sikh? Then what are Khem Singh Bedi and the Singh Saba?

Comment: @Sikhandyeshallfind Before 1870s sikh term was used for "khalsa sikh" and "sanatani sikh". Both followed same teachings, except that some sanatani sikh do not followed 5Ks. Main difference was that Khalsa sikh beleived that Sikhism is separate religion evolved from hinduism, and sanatani sikhs beleived that their sikhism is a sect within hinduism. Finally both had separate followings. But during 1920s finally Khalsas could get control on gurudwaras. Shankaracharya, Gandhiji all supported Khalsas on this issue.. Now 'currently' term 'sikhism' is mostly used as synonym only for 'Khalsa sikhs'.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan , Udasis are a sect created by Sri Chand , one of the two sons of Guru Nanak. Sri Chand and Lakhmi Chand both did not obey their father and he instead chose to pass his guruship to his obedient disciple who became second guru of sikhs. Sri Chand is not spoken of in nice terms in Sikh scriptures.

Comment: Secondly, when sikhs were fighting against mughals in the 18th century, they were outlawed and had to resort to jungle, deserts and swamps to survive. The management of gurudwaras thus passed in hands of Udasis , Later the udasis became corrupt and tried to mix hindu and sikh beliefs such as idol worship in golden temple. Singh Sabha was a reactionary movement to bring the golden temple and other gurudwaras back to how they were in the first place. I don't know about Khem Singh bedi , but today Bedi clan is found among both hindus and sikhs in punjab, Hindu bedis also revere Guru Nanak AFAIK

Comment: https://www.sikhnet.com/news/sindhi-hindus-nanakpanthis-pakistan
shows that even "in pakistan" also currently still there are nanakpanthis and udasis. and this article explains a lot of detail about this sect even in pakistan.

Comment: Udasis and Sikh relationship spoiled especially during the Nanakana massacre . When the corrupt Udasi Mahant of Nanakana (birth place of Nanak) got many sikhs killed by his goons . Udasis live somewhere on the fuzzy borders of hinduism and sikhism.
There exists one more such sect , the nirmalas , they however are far more respected than udasis by mainstream sikhs. If I remember correctly they believe in vedas too, and are identified by ochre-colored robes that they wear like angavastram. However the guru had said "Khalsa mero roop hai khaas" (Khalsa is my purest form).

Comment: @zaxebo1 , yes udasis are also found often in Kumbh mela I think. 
It is also believed by some that the 17th asthapadi (octet, astha in sanskrit means 8)  of Sukhmani sahib (a composition in SGGS)  was composed by Sri Chand when he visited Guru Arjan , the 5th sikh guru, however this is largely disputed .